# Open File dialog box to get Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I've written some Word VBA which takes an Excel file and updates Labels (ActiveX Control) in the Word file.  The only thing is this Excel file will change path and filename each month.  Instead of editing 2 variables each month, how do I add an Open File dialog box so the user selects the Excel file to be used?

Here is what I have now:

```
Sub Update()
    Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application
    Dim exWb As Excel.Workbook

    PathWork = "C:\My Documents\2015-05 Report\"
    CalcFile = "May2015-data.xlsx"

    Set exWb=objExcel.Workbooks.Open(FileName:=PathWork & CalcFile)
    ThisDocument.date.Caption=exWb.Sheets("Data").Cells(1,1)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simplified macro which will allow the user to select only Macro-Enabled Excels. I couldn't comment on the previous answer as I have not earned enough reputation to comment on an answer. Please mind it.

```
Public Sub GetCaptionFromExcel()
    Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application, exWb As Workbook
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .Title = "Select Macro-Enabled Excel Files"
        .Filters.Add "Macro-Enabled Excel Files", "*.xlsm", 1
        If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub

        Set exWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(.SelectedItems(1))
        '*** Use the values from excel here***
        MsgBox exWb.Sheets("Data").Cells(1, 1)
        '*** Close the opened Excel file
        exWb.Close
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

Replace `PathWork` and `CalcFile` with `Dialogbox`

```
With Dialogs(wdDialogFileOpen)
    If .Display Then
        If .Name <> "" Then
            Set exWb = Workbooks.Open(.Name)
            sPath = exWb.Path
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "No file selected"
    End If
End With
```

Complete  <kbd>**CODE**</kbd>  should look like this

```
Option Explicit

Sub Update()
    Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application
    Dim exWb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim sPath As String

    '// Dialog box here to select excel file
    With Dialogs(wdDialogFileOpen)
        If .Display Then
            If .Name <> "" Then
                Set exWb = Workbooks.Open(.Name)
                sPath = exWb.Path
            End If
            Set exWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(FileName:=sPath)
            ActiveDocument.Date.Caption = exWb.Sheets("Data").Cells(1, 1)
        Else
            MsgBox "No file selected"
        End If
    End With
    Set objExcel = Nothing
    Set exWb = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Omar! But how would I integrate that with the code I showed?  That's my main Word VBA macro, except there are many lines of .Caption linked to my Excel object exWb

Comment: @wongnog see updated answer, i didn't test yet but i will as soon i get a min.

Comment: Thanks Omar, I think it's almost there!  Your code is expecting a Word document though, and doesn't like when I try and pass through an Excel file (gives a Run-time error '5792': The file appears to be corrupted).  Can you please help me filter it for macro-enabled Excel files (.xlsm)? Thanks!

Comment: it lets me open any file type now, but now I get a `Run-time error '1004': "myfile.xlsm" could not be found. Check the spelling of the file name, and verify that the file location is correct.` I'm guessing there is a syntax error with the path / filename?